# Sending the timing from the page load to the last occurrence of a button click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-analytics

I want to keep track of the time it takes for a user to use a configuration page, which is the total time from first loading the page to the last time the user presses the save button. Pressing the save button does NOT reload the page.

I do not want to rely on Google's average page time calculation since that calculation does not count the last visited page and is thus not that accurate.

I could perform a

```
ga('send', 'timing', 'SaveTime', 'SaveTimeVar', timeSpent);
```

After every time the save button is pressed but it does not give me the time value I want, which is the total time from page load to LAST save button press.  The problem is due to the fact that it is impossible to know if the current save event is the last one.

Any ideas?

Comment: What if they load the page, get distracted and don't complete it today?

Comment: Then I guess we can ignore that session? Are you suggesting we somehow have an upper limit for the maximum amount of time a user has on the page? What level of code will handle that?

Comment: The problem is knowing. You have to design for your upper time limit.

Comment: Right. So suppose I have this arbitrary limit. Then can I run an ajax call to inform a php file that the button has been pressed. The php file can then calculate the difference after the upper limit expires?